# Moving files or directories with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I don't get it.  I created a folder.  Added it using the SVN Add command.  Then took one of the files that was already versioned and right mouse moved it.  When I got the context menu I selected "SVN Move versioned Items here"

Ok fine, it moved.  But it deleted and then re-added that file.  Now when I right-click that file in its new location and view log, I get no history..like it started from scratch again.  I only get the one item in the log that says I moved it.  What happened to all its history! ??

Comment: Did you try to look at the log before or after you committed your change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the checkbox you're looking for is "Stop on Copy/Rename" in the Log dialog.  If this is checked, you will only see revisions in which the file existed at its current path.  If you uncheck it, you should be able to see the history back as far as it exists in the repository, including at other paths.

@Thorarin, Subversion has supported moving files since long before 1.5.

Comment: ah, I guess the "Move Here" is just windows explorer.  I did not know this because I never right click files to move them outside of Subversion. Nice.

Comment: @Thorarin, yes, they made some enhancements in 1.5 that are detailed there, but the basic concept of copying/moving a file and keeping history existed before that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to view log with option uncheck "hide unrelated changed paths" and see. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Subversion prior to 1.5, this is normal. Starting with 1.5 it supports moving files though.

I haven't used subversion or tortoise all that much since then though. I hadn't moved anything until just now :) The *Hide unrelated changed paths* checkbox seems to be what you're looking for indeed.

When browsing the repository, I see revisions prior to the move, so if you aren't, I guess it's time to upgrade to a more recent version?

Comment: so then what's the difference between Svn Move and Move versioned file or folder?